# Android location manager permissions to be used

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, locationmanager

I have the following code in my android project:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
location = currentLocation.getLatitude() + " " + currentLocation.getLongitude();
MyLocation.setText(location);
```

I am getting an `provider == null`  error. what permissions do I need to use?

My android manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.DuckTag"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".DuckTagActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Just for reference, you don't actually need both these permissions unless you use both (which the OP does in this case). See the developer [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for more information.

Comment: You _don't_ need both Permissions. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION includes ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Answer (score 38):

Here is what you need to add to your manifest file

### GPS-based location

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

---

### Network-based location

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Previous posters are wrong, if you want to use both, then only `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is required, as detailed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

> Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then
>   you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because
>   it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to add to your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

for GPS-based location or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

for network-based location

You can require both if you want to build a more versatile application.

Greetings,
 Stéphane